# Watershed delineation using hydrological Python library

Tags: python, dem, hydrology, watershed

We would like to delineate watershed polygon for a given pour point using hydrological Python library.
Until now, we have tried these libraries:

- pyshed
- Grass (r.watershed)
- Whitetoolbox

We have around 1200 pour points for which we would like to determine a watershed area.

Our generated flow direction for a given DEM seems valid but we do not know why we always get a strange watershed result.

Here is an example of what we have obtained for this pour point:

[image]

The calculated watershed area corresponds to this (the black pixel):
[image]

Did you already get this kind of strange results?

What could cause such results?

Could projection impact the calculation?

I do not know what we do wrong but we always obtains an invalid watershed result.

You can my drive folder URL where you find the DEM and the pour point used in my example.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LHkNDnDVNSLgx6Lw894mxL5XShHS1EWs?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you run the DEM through a fill sinks tool BEFORE you attempt to generate a flow direction raster?

Comment: How are you calculating the flow direction map? r.watershed? if yes, you should be able to get the accumulation map too. Hw does it look like. It seems your pour points are just off the "streams" or larger accumulation cells. Depending on the raster you are using, it might be that there is a small difference between the lowest point and the pour point, ending the last one not being in the stream line.

Comment: Thank you for your supports. I did fill the pits before as recommended. The problem was the position of the pour points. It was not well positionned. As soon as I have moved the pour point at the proper position the watershed were well deliniated.